# Overload of operator() for a CUDA matrix class

Tags: c++, class, cuda, operator-overloading

I have both CPU and GPU (CUDA) matrix classes and I want to overload the `operator()` so that I can read or write individual elements of the matrices.

For the CPU matrix class, I was able to do so by

```
OutType & operator()(const int i) { return data_[i]; }
```

(read) and

```
OutType operator()(const int i) const { return data_[i]; }
```

(write). For the GPU matrix class, I was able to overload the `operator()` for reading by

```
__host__ OutType operator()(const int i) const { OutType d; CudaSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(&d,data_+i,sizeof(OutType),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)); return d; }
```

but I was unable to do the same for writing. Could someone provide any hint to solve this issue?

The writing case for CPU returns the reference of `data_[i]`, so the assignment job is performed by the builting C++ `operator=`. I cannot figure out how could I exploit the same mechanism for CUDA.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate class that has overloaded assignment operator and type cast operator and emulates reference behavior:

```
class DeviceReferenceWrapper
{
public:
    explicit DeviceReferenceWrapper(void* ptr) : ptr_(ptr) {}

    DeviceReferenceWrapper& operator =(int val)
    {
        cudaMemcpy(ptr_, &val, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        return *this;
    }

    operator int() const
    {
        int val;
        cudaMemcpy(&val, ptr_, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        return val;
    }

private:
    void* ptr_;
};
```

and use it in matrix class

```
class Matrix
{
    DeviceReferenceWrapper operator ()(int i)
    {
        return DeviceReferenceWrapper(data + i);
    }
};
```

Comment: Very clever solution! Thank you very much. Just to clarify to other potentially interested users. This solution works for both the "reading" and "writing" case. Again, thanks.